# Getting the empty set of arrays while reading the excel file

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I am using this library to read the excel file https://github.com/trevordixon/excel.js

It is working on localhost as expected but not on the AWS server.
I am using the same version of node and npm on both side.

```
**code:**

router.post('/uploadDataViaExcel', upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {

 //console.log("res",res);
 //console.log(req.body, 'Body');
 //console.log(req.files, 'files');

  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(req.files[0].filename);
  console.log("file name "+myJSON);

  if (typeof myJSON != 'undefined'){

    var filename=req.files[0].filename;

    console.log("File type is ",req.files[0].mimetype);

    var spreadsheet_path=path.resolve('./public/uploads/');

    console.log("final path ",spreadsheet_path+'/'+filename);

    parseXlsx(spreadsheet_path+'/'+filename, function(err, data) {

        console.log("inside xlsx");

        if (err){
          console.log("err is ",err);
        }else {

          console.log("process start");

          console.log("data",data);

          var itemAdded=2;

           console.log("data length ",data.length);

          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            if (i===0) {
              //do nothing
            }else {
              var tempData=data[i];

              console.log("tempData ",tempData);

                modelMember.addMemberViaExcel(tempData, function(err, result){

                  if (err) {
                  //  console.log(" final err",err);
                    if (itemAdded==data.length) {
                      //console.log("result outer ",result);

                      var obj= new Object();
                      obj.status=true;
                      obj.message="Data Added Successfully.";

                      return res.json(obj);
                    }
                    itemAdded=itemAdded+1;

                  }
                  else {

                    if (itemAdded==data.length) {
                      console.log("result outer ",result);

                      var obj= new Object();
                      obj.status=true;
                      obj.message="Data Added Successfully.";

                       return res.json(obj);
                    }

                    itemAdded=itemAdded+1;
                  }
                })
            }

          }
        }
      });



    //end of if

  }else {
     var obj= new Object();
     obj.status=false;
     obj.message="Error while uploading file try again";

     res.json(obj);
   }

//  res.end();
});
```

Node:v8.9.3
npm:v5.5.1

On the localhost, it is working perfectly. 
The flow of program: uploading the excel file using multer package and save it in puble/upload folder. Then access it. But when I am doing on server then it is giving me empty list of data.